# character encoding issue in converting csv data using fileInputStream class in java

Tags: java, csv, fileinputstream

Hi am having a csv file in my hand and am trying to read each line in csv file and update the content to a database table. Am doing this using java.

Following are the things i did for achieving this.

```
FileInputStream fileInputStream = FileUtils.openInputStream("filename.csv");
dataInputStream = new DataInputStream(fileInputStream);
BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(dataInputStream));
String strLine;
while((strLine = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null){
        System.out.println(strLine);
}
```

but its printing something like `blocks` on the console, not the actual data csv having

can anyone please help me to solve this issue.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should find out what encoding it is and then declare it while reading, xample for UTF-16:

```
new InputStreamReader(zipFile.getInputStream(entry), "UTF_16" )
```

Comment: To check automatically rather than manually guessing the file's encoding, you can use [ICU4J](http://site.icu-project.org/)

Comment: how can i determine the type of character encoding used in the csv file using the above link you had given..?

Comment: very nice suggestion eee i will definitly be using that in the future. @tijoKVagrhese try http://userguide.icu-project.org/conversion/detection